# Flutter - display json array into exapnsion tile

Tags: json, flutter

i am new to flutter currently i m trying to make a gujrati news app and i m taking data from the json.

i m trying to get data from a url and try to display it in expansion tile.

below is the json file:

```
    { "editorial" : 
[ { 
"Id" : "27740",
"title" : "ભારત-અમેરિકા સંરક્ષણ સહયોગમાં હરણફાળ ",
"description" : "અમેરિકાના બે સિનિયર મંત્રીઓની ભારતયાત્રા તેમજ 2+2 બેઠકમાં બીઇસીએ સમજૂતી સહિતના અનેક કરારથી બંને દેશોનો લશ્કરી સહયોગ નવી ઊંચાઇએ પહોંચ્યો છે. ઘરઆંગણે બીજી મુદ્દત મેળવવા તત્પર રાષ્ટ્રપ્રમુખ ડોનાલ્ડ ટ્રમ્પ પ્રચાર ઝુંબેશમાં ભારતની આબોહવા કે પ્રદૂષણ સ્તર વિશે ભલે નકારાત્મક ટિપ્પણી કરતા હોય પણ ટ્રમ્પ સરકારની આ પહેલ દર્શાવે છે કે, બંને દેશ એકબીજા પર ખૂબ ભરોસો કરે છે અને કદીએ ન્હોતી એવી નિકટતાના સ્તરે પહોંચી ચૂક્યા છે. બેઝિક એક્સચેન્જ એન્ડ કો-ઓપરેશન એગ્રીમેન્ટ (બીઇસીએ) પછી અમેરિકા ભારતને કોઇપણ વિસ્તાર સાથે સંકળાયેલી જિયો સ્પૈરિયલ માહિતી ઉપલબ્ધ કરાવશે. ભવિષ્યમાં બાલાકોટ જેવા કોઇપણ?ઓપરેશન વખતે શત્રુઓના લક્ષ્ય પર આપણા મિસાઇલ કે બોમ્બ સચોટ નિશાન લગાવી શકશે. ગુપ્ત લશ્કરી સેટેલાઇટ ડેટા ભારતને મળવો એ ચીન અને પાકિસ્તાન માટે સારા સમાચાર નથી. દેખીતી રીતે બીજિંગના પેટમાં તેલ રેડાયું છે. પ્રતિક્રિયામાં ચીને અમેરિકા પર ભારતની ચડામણી કરવાનો આક્ષેપ કરતાં જણાવ્યું છે કે, ભારત-ચીન સીમા વિવાદ દ્વિપક્ષીય મામલો છે. તેના પર મંત્રણા જારી છે પરંતુ અમેરિકા બેઅસર બની ચૂકેલી શીત યુદ્ધની નીતિ અપનાવી રહ્યું છે. અલબત્ત, ચીનની વાતોનો ભરોસો કોઇ કાળે થઇ?શકે એમ નથી. ગલવાન ખીણની અથડામણ અને આપણા 20 વીર જવાનની શહીદી અને એ પછી પણ?લગાતાર આક્રમક તેવર તેના વિસ્તારવાદનું પ્રમાણ છે. વિવિધ સ્તરની મંત્રણા છતાં તે લદ્દાખ સીમાના કેટલાય વિસ્તારોમાંથી પીછેહઠ કરવા તૈયાર નથી, પરંતુ હવે તેને અહેસાસ થતો હશે કે ભારતને ઓછું આંકવામાં તેણે ગંભીર ભૂલ કરી છે. અમેરિકા હવે સરાજાહેર ભારતની પક્ષે અને ચીનથી વિરુદ્ધ આવી ગયું છે. ભારત-અમેરિકા 2+2 મંત્રણા પછીની પત્રકાર પરિષદમાં અમેરિકી વિદેશમંત્રી માઇક પોમ્પિયોએ ચીનની સત્તાધારી કોમ્યુનિસ્ટ પાર્ટીને લોકતંત્ર અને પારદર્શિતાની દુશ્મન લેખાવી. એટલું જ નહીં ગલવાનમાં શહીદ ભારતીય જવાનોનો ઉલ્લેખ કરીને તેમણે કહ્યું કે, અમેરિકા ભારતની જનતાની પડખે ઊભું છે. પોમ્પિયો અને તેમના સાથી સંરક્ષણમંત્રી માર્ક એસ્પર વડાપ્રધાન નરેન્દ્ર મોદીને મળ્યા હતા અને વિસ્તૃત ચર્ચા કરી હતી. રાષ્ટ્રીય સુરક્ષા સલાહકાર અજિત દોભાલ સાથે પણ ચીન સાથેના સંઘર્ષ અંગે વાતચીત કરી હતી. ભારતના સંરક્ષણમંત્રી રાજનાથસિંહ અને વિદેશમંત્રી એસ. જયશંકર અમેરિકા સાથેની નિકટતા અને ચીનના પ્રતિકાર માટે લાંબા સમયથી સક્રિય રહ્યા છે. પડોશી પાકિસ્તાનના બિનભરોસાપાત્ર વલણ અને ચીનના લગાતાર વધતા ખતરાને જોતાં સુરક્ષા મામલાને મોદી સરકારે ઉચ્ચ પ્રાથમિકતા આપી છે. બીઇસીએ સમજૂતી પૂર્વે 2002માં બંને દેશો વચ્ચે લશ્કરી માહિતીની આપ-લેના કરાર થયા હતા. એ વખતે અમેરિકા પર આતંકી હુમલો થયો હતો અને આતંકવાદનો મુકાબલો કરવા માટે ભારત જેવા દેશના સાથની તેને જરૂર હતી. 2016 અને 2018માં સંરક્ષણ?સામગ્રીની આપૂર્તિ અને સુરક્ષાને લગતા બે કરાર થયા હતા. બીઇસીએ સમજૂતી એ કડીનો એક ભાગ છે. ભારત સંતુલન જાળવીને લશ્કરી ક્ષમતા સતત મજબૂત કરી રહ્યું છે. જૂનું ભાઇબંધ?રશિયા પણ આપણને મદદ કરી રહ્યું છે. બેફામ ચીનને નાથવા ભારત-અમેરિકી સમજૂતીઓ બ્રહ્માત્ર પુરવાર થવાની ક્ષમતા રાખે છે. આશા રાખીએ આ કડક સંદેશ પછી ચીન સુધરશે અને ભારતને કનડવાનું બંધ કરશે.'"} ,
 { 
"Id" : "27739",
"title" : "સિંગતેલ મોંઘુદાટ ",
"description" : "ગુજરાતમાં આ વેળા સારા વરસાદના કારણે મગફળીનો વિપુલ પાક થયો છે અને સૌરાષ્ટ્ર સહિત ગુજરાતના માર્કેટ યાર્ડોમાં મગફળીની ધૂમ આવક થઇ રહી છે. સોમવારે તો ગુજરાતના યાર્ડોમાં આઠ લાખ ગૂણીની આવક થઇ હતી જે ઐતિહાસિક ગણાય છે. રાજકોટ અને ગોંડલ યાર્ડમાં 1 થી દોઢ લાખ ગૂણી મગફળીની આવક થઇ રહી છે, એટલું જ નહીં નાના યાર્ડમાં ધૂમ આવક છે. આ વેળા મગફળીનો પાક 35 લાખ ટનથી વધુ હોવાના અંદાજો મુકાયા છે જે પણ ઐતિહાસિક છે, પણ પાછોતરા વરસાદના કારણે પાકના અંદાજો ઘટવા લાગ્યા છે છતાં 25થી 30 લાખ ટન પાક ગણાઈ રહ્યો છે અને સૌથી સારી વાત એ છે કે મગફળીના સારા ભાવ ખેડૂતોને યાર્ડોમાં મળી રહ્યા છે. સરેરાશ મણનો ભાવ 1,000થી 1,100 મળી રહ્યો છે અને આ કારણે ખેડૂતો મગફળી સંઘરવાનું મુનાસીબ માનતા નથી અને લોકડાઉન અને પછી અનલોક સમયમાં આર્થિક સમસ્યા વધી છે અને દિવાળીના તહેવારો આવી ગયા છે, ત્યારે ખેડૂત મગફળી વેચી આર્થિક સમસ્યા હળવી કરવા તત્પર છે અને મગફળીની સરકારી ખરીદીમાં ઓછો રસ દાખવી રહ્યા છે. કારણ કે અત્યારે ખુલ્લા બજારમાં ખેડૂતને સારા ભાવ મળી રહ્યા છે. સરકારી ભાવ રૂા. 1055 છે . બીજું કે, સરકારી ખરીદીમાં રજિસ્ટ્રેશનની પ્રક્રિયા છે અને માલ વેચાયા પછી એકાદ મહિને નાણા મળે છે. ગયા વર્ષે ખેડૂતોને ખુલ્લા બજારમાં ભાવ ઓછા મળતા હતા એ કારણે સરકારી ખરીદી વધી હતી. આ વેળા ગયા વર્ષ કરતાં સરકારી ખરીદી ઓછી થાય એવી શક્યતા જણાઈ રહી છે. સરકાર પર એટલો આર્થિક બોજ ઘટશે, પણ મગફળીનો વિપુલ પાક' હોવા છતાં સિંગતેલના ભાવ પણ વિક્રમી સપાટીએ પહોંચ્યા છે. અત્યારે સિંગતેલના દબાણો ભાવ રૂા. 2,300ની સપાટી વળોટી ચૂક્યો છે, એટલે ખાનારા વર્ગને કોઈ ફાયદો થયો નથી. આ મુદ્દે સરકારે દરમિયાનગીરી કરવી કે કેમ એ નક્કી કરવાનો સમય છે. કારણ કે અત્યારે ચીનમાં સિંગતેલની મોટાપાયે નિકાસ થઇ રહી છે અને ટનનો ભાવ 2,200 ડોલર સુધી પહોંચ્યો છે અને આ કારણે મગફળીના ભાવ વધ્યા છે. સરકારે બજાર પર ચાંપતી નજર રાખવાની જરૂર છે. કારણ કે સિંગતેલના ભાવ વધતાં બજારમાં ફરસાણના ભાવ પણ ઠીક ઠીક વધ્યા છે. જો કે, બહુ ઓછા ફરસાણવાળા સિંગતેલ વાપરે છે. સિંગતેલનો ભાવ હંમેશાં ગુજરાતમાં સંવેદનશીલ પ્રશ્ન રહ્યો છે. ખેડૂતોને પૂરતા ભાવ મળે એ આવશ્યક છે પણ સિંગતેલના ભાવ વધુ પડતી ઊંચી સપાટીએ પહોંચે તો અન્ય તેલોના ભાવ પર પણ એની અસર પડતી હોય છે. સિંગતેલના ભાવ ફરી મુદ્દો ન બને અને એમાં રાજકારણ ન પ્રવેશે એ જોવાની સરકારની ફરજ છે. ' "} ] }
```

i have tried this :

```
class EditorialPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditorialPageState createState() => _EditorialPageState();
}

class _EditorialPageState extends State<EditorialPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<EditorialPage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  BuildContext context1;
  List<User> listModel = [];
  var loading = false;

Future<Null> getData() async{
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    DateTime oops = DateTime.now();
    String d_date = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(oops);

    final response = await http.get("..." + d_date);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      setState(() {
        for(Map i in data){
          listModel.add(User.fromJson(i));
        }
        print(listModel[0].editorial.id);
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    DateTime oops = DateTime.now();
    String d_date = DateFormat('ddMMyyyy').format(oops);

    var url =  '...' + d_date;
    final validCharacters = RegExp(r':[]^[a-zA-Z0:]}-9_\-=@,\.;]+$, "');

    print(url);
    var response = await http.get('$url',
        headers: {"charset": "utf-8", "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"});
    String utfDecode = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);

    return utfDecode.replaceAll(":", "");
  }

  Future loadyourData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

// this is the local json that i have loaded from the assets folder
// you can make the http call here and else everything later is the same.

    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    // loading the json from the asset the above line
    String newStr = jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length - 1);
    // removing the "[ ]" from the json where we can interpreat it as a map
    // you can use it your way for if removing and or using the list, but at last taking it into the list of object

    print(newStr);
    Map newStringMap = json.decode(newStr);
    var list = new List();
    newStringMap.forEach((key, value) {
      list.add(value);
    });

    for (var newsList in list) {
      var news = User.fromJson(newsList);
      listModel.add(news);
    }
    print(listModel[0].editorial.title);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    //loadyourData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime oops = DateTime.now();

    return Container(
        child: Container(
          child: _isLoading
              ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
              : ListView.builder(
            //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: listModel.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              final nDataList = listModel[i];
              return SizedBox(
                height: 130.0,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text(
                      nDataList.editorial.title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        //title
                        fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        nDataList.editorial.description,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          //title
                          fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

i am getting this exception when i am initializing loadyourData():

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 14)
E/flutter (12978):  "editorial" : ] }
E/flutter (12978):              ^
E/flutter (12978): 
E/flutter (12978): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (12978): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:891:42)
E/flutter (12978): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter (12978): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:505:36)
E/flutter (12978): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:156:41)
E/flutter (12978): #5      _EditorialPageState.loadyourData (package:.../editorial.dart:71:29)
```

i am getting this exception when i am initializing getData():

```
E/flutter (12978): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 3, character 1)
E/flutter (12978): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www....
E/flutter (12978): ^
E/flutter (12978): 
E/flutter (12978): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
```

How can i display the above url data in expansion tile

Comment: The error caused is due to a JSON format error

Comment: i tried it on online jsonparse there is no formot error in it.

Comment: ok , so what ido you see on the logs when you `print(newStr);`? or even better `print('|$newStr|')`?

Comment: "editorial"  ] }
I/flutter (12978): 
I/flutter (12978): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http//www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

i see this


it is a json array and from that i have to get the data

Comment: @SamkitShah will run your code and see

Comment: as i said it is a json array and i have given parameter of response.bodybytes instead of response.body i tried with body also it is showing same

Comment: could you post what does `print('|$newStr|')` show on the logs? as you can see you are calling `json.decode(newStr);` so `newStr` has to be a valid json data

Comment: i can but it is going out of characters as i told you that avoid comments and transfer to chat

Comment: so post first, lets say, 16 characters and last 16 characters

Comment: "editorial" : ] }
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
</title></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="./jsonEditorial.aspx?siteId=3&amp;pDate=29102020" id="form1">

<div>     
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

here it is

Comment: i dont see any `DOCTYPE` in your original file, but anyway, your data starts with `"editorial" :` which is not a valid json, for example: `{"name":"John"}` is valid, but `"name":"John"` is not

Comment: @pskink areee what i am saying is it a json array instead of reponse.bodybytes it should be response.body in my code see my code wait i will update one more method. now see i added a getData() see in what i m getting this E/flutter (12978): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 3, character 1)
E/flutter (12978): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www....
E/flutter (12978): ^

Comment: so you have html data, not json, what are `response.headers`? is there some `Content-Type` or similar header? is it `application/json` or `text/html`?

Comment: no its a .aspx file here is the url https://www.kutchmitradaily.com/jsonEditorial.aspx?siteId=3&pDate=29/10/2020

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### First getting the data and storing it in a local `JSON` file:

*PS: go through the comments too.*

The `downloadFile()` function will make a `get` post request and then write the data to a local file in app Support Directory.

```
downloadFile() async {
  // Your stored url.
  String url =
      "https://www.kutchmitradaily.com/jsonEditorial.aspx?siteId=3&pDate=29/10/2020";
  
  // Getting the http response
  Response response = await get(url);
  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  print(statusCode); // for debugging purpose
  
  //This will remove the html tags if any
  String body = response.body.replaceAll(
      RegExp(
        r"<[^>]*>",
        multiLine: true,
        caseSensitive: true,
      ),
      '');
  //Writing the body to a json
  String path = await getPath();
  File jsonFile = File('$path/jsonFile.json');
  jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(body);
}
```

### Getting Path of the Android/ios App Support Directory folder:

This uses the `PathProvider` plugin to get the app support directory path and the `getPath()` function will simply return the path.

```
Future<String> get applicationSupportFileDirectoryPath async {
  String applicationSupportDirectoryPath;
  final getApplicationDirectory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  applicationSupportDirectoryPath = getApplicationDirectory.path;
  return applicationSupportDirectoryPath;
}

getPath() async {
  String path;
  await applicationSupportFileDirectoryPath.then((value) {
    path = value;
  });
  print('[P] path returned : $path');
  return path;
}
```

You can merge both functions as a single function, but be sure the process(steps) happens synchronously.

### Reading the JSON file.

This Function will run the `downloadFile()` first and then proceed to read the file and strong the values to a local dart variable.

*This function returns the same `content` variable, this is done for the `FutureBuilder()` widget to check if data is available or not, if no then it will show a `CircularProgressIndicator()` widget*

```
// Declared out of the function  
int listLength;
List content = [];

readFile() async {
    // Downloading the file before reading;
    await downloadFile();

    // read the file:
    String path = await getPath();
    String jsonFile = File('$path/jsonFile.json').readAsStringSync();

    Map dJson = json.decode(jsonFile);
    List editorial = dJson['editorial'];

    // Storing the read data in local variables.
    listLength = editorial.length;
    return content = editorial;
  }
```

### Now Using the Data In Widget:

This Step depends upon you, use an inside of `expansion tile` for your case.

The `readFile()` function stores the  `"editorial" : [ ..., ..., ...,]` JSON structure(**editorial is a `List` datatype**) to `content` variable.
Now each `List item` is of map Datatype, keep this in mind.

What I did is used `ListView.builder()`  and dynamically created the list.

eg:
I created a function `getId()`

```
getId(index) {
    Map data = content[index];
    return data["Id"];
  }
```

This function takes an index as parameter, now while building `ListView` using the `ListView.builder()` it passes the current `index` of the list in `ItemBuilder`,

now inside the `getId()` func,
I used that index and store the respective index `Map` data by accessing the key to get the id like this `return data['Id'];` where `Id` is the key in the `JSON` structure inside `editorial` list.

---

### Whole Code

**Pubscpec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  path_provider: ^1.6.22 #add this.
  http: ^0.12.2 #add this
```

**main.dart:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Json http request',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  int listLength;
  List content = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: readFile(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, process) {
          Widget builder;
          if (process.hasData) {
            builder = Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listLength,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    tileColor: Colors.pink,
                    title: Text(getTitle(index)),
                    //subtitle: Text(getDescription(index)),
                    leading: Text(
                      getId(index),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            builder = Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
            );
          }
          return builder;
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  readFile() async {
    // Downloading the file before reading;
    await downloadFile();

    // read the file:
    String path = await getPath();
    String jsonFile = File('$path/jsonFile.json').readAsStringSync();

    Map dJson = json.decode(jsonFile);
    List editorial = dJson['editorial'];

    // Storing the read data in local variables.
    listLength = editorial.length;
    return content = editorial;
  }

  getId(index) {
    Map data = content[index];
    return data["Id"];
  }

  getTitle(index) {
    Map data = content[index];
    return data["title"];
  }

  getDescription(index) {
    Map data = content[index];
    return data["description"];
  }
}

downloadFile() async {
  String url =
      "https://www.kutchmitradaily.com/jsonEditorial.aspx?siteId=3&pDate=29/10/2020";

  Response response = await get(url);
  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  print(statusCode);

  String body = response.body.replaceAll(
      RegExp(
        r"<[^>]*>",
        multiLine: true,
        caseSensitive: true,
      ),
      '');
  //Writing the body to a json
  String path = await getPath();
  File jsonFile = File('$path/jsonFile.json');
  jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(body);
}

Future<String> get applicationSupportFileDirectoryPath async {
  String applicationSupportDirectoryPath;
  final getApplicationDirectory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  applicationSupportDirectoryPath = getApplicationDirectory.path;
  return applicationSupportDirectoryPath;
}

getPath() async {
  String path;
  await applicationSupportFileDirectoryPath.then((value) {
    path = value;
  });
  print('[P] path returned : $path');
  return path;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: i apperciate your work but i am taking it from a url not local

Comment: yeah then just download and store it temp folder or app support directory then you can use the above code

Comment: add the Url I will write a code block and add to the answer.

Comment: https://www.kutchmitradaily.com/jsonEditorial.aspx?siteId=3&pDate=29/10/2020 thank you bro apperciate it.

Comment: where should i put the url to fetch the data?

Comment: simple in the initState()  as I have included the readFile

Comment: @SamkitShah your URL includes `html` tags as Http get response body, any tip how you avoided that?

Comment: @SamkitShah Updating the whole answer

Comment: Thank you @Adithya Shetty
yess will update the answer.